# How to pass Join Data to View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

I am New one to MVC. Here I have joined 4 tables and retrieved data successfully but I don't know how to pass this data's to view.

Please, anyone, help me. Thanks in advance.

**Controller code**

```
public class EditController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

                    MachineTest1DbEntities entity = new MachineTest1DbEntities();
                    var entryPoint = (from Tt in entity.TransactionTables
                    join pm in entity.Projectmasters on Tt.ProjectId equals pm.ProjectId
                    join ps in entity.ProjectStatusmasters on Tt.ProjectStatusId equals ps.ProjectStatusId
                    join mm in entity.Modulemasters on Tt.ModuleId equals mm.ModuleId

                    select Tt
                );


        return View(entryPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a Custom model with the properties you want to display on view.

for eg.

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public int ProjectId{ get; set; }
    public string  ProjectName { get; set; } 
    public string  ProjectStatus { get; set; } 
}
```

At action method, map the selected result to the custom model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     MachineTest1DbEntities entity = new MachineTest1DbEntities();
     var result= (from Tt in entity.TransactionTables
            join pm in entity.Projectmasters on Tt.ProjectId equals pm.ProjectId
            join ps in entity.ProjectStatusmasters on Tt.ProjectStatusId equals 
            ps.ProjectStatusId
            join mm in entity.Modulemasters on Tt.ModuleId equals mm.ModuleId
            select new ResultModel
                       {
                           ProjectId= Tt.ProjectId,
                           ProjectName = Tt.ProjectName ,
                           ProjectStatus =Tt.ProjectStatus 
                       }).ToList();      
     return View(result);
}
```

and then use model like this at your view :`@model List<ResultModel>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add .ToList() to the IQueryable returned result, and later send it to your view. 
This will send a list to your View which u can iterate with foreach(var item in Model):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var result= (from Tt in entity.TransactionTables
                join pm in entity.Projectmasters on Tt.ProjectId equals pm.ProjectId
                join ps in entity.ProjectStatusmasters on Tt.ProjectStatusId equals 
                ps.ProjectStatusId
                join mm in entity.Modulemasters on Tt.ModuleId equals mm.ModuleId

                select Tt
            ).ToList();


    return View(result);
}
```